# Большой как статусный: нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Большой человек" в значении "статусный" берется в кавычки? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы взял в кавычки, если это сарказм. В значении "статусный" или "имеющий большой размер (толстый или высокий)" кавычки не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Это стилистический вопрос, я считаю. Я бы не брал, если в контексте понятно, что имеется в виду именно "статусный".

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не нужны, значение большой = статусный уже не является чем-то необычным или оккажиональным.